# Graph Checkin method returns empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-checkins, real-time-updates

I'm trying to get to work the Checkin method, but currently I only get empty data:

```
{  "data": [  ]}
```

Whether using this http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fcheckins or using https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN I only get no data. I've checked in several locations, I has been tagged also in photos taken and uploaded using location; but no luck.

The main goal is to get RTU working with checkin events working...but, if I can not get it to work with the api explorer I can not expect to get it working with RTU...

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the `user_checkins` permission from the user you're trying to check? Check with a call to `/me/permissions`

Also, are you sure the user has recent checkins? If they're not recent you may need to increase the limit on the query or add a `since` parameter

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Permissions has been granted to my application, since I'm the only subscriber I auto gave me permissions, this can be checked accessing this url: https://api.facebook.com/method/users.hasAppPermission?ext_perm=user_checkins&uid=UID&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN (ACCESS_TOKEN=token given to my application; running /me returns the correct set of permissions). The user (me) has uploaded photos using location, friends of mine also did the same and I get no updates.

Comment: I think there's a distinction between 'check in' and 'photo with a location' - i think only the first one is actually available in the API at the moment - might be worth filing a wishlist item in Facebook's bug tracker about this

Comment: So there is a difference you said, between "checking in" and "location within a photo"? I thought the only way to check in was to set the location of something (photo or anything else that can have a location). I'm gonna check the FB bug tracker and see what can I get, I'll keep the post updated. Thank you.